# Getting webpack error "Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module" in fluxible after re-installing node_modules

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, fluxible

I have a fluxible project and I'm getting these errors after I deleted all files in node_modules and reinstalled with `npm install -d` when I try to run with `npm run dev` which is `node webpack-dev-server.js & PORT=3001 nodemon start.js -e js,jsx`.  The app was working fine until I reinstalled dependencies.

Here's the fluxible template project

https://github.com/yahoo/generator-fluxible

What is causing these errors and how can I diagnose?  Why did it work initially and then stopped working when I reinstalled node modules?

```
ERROR in ./client.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js' in /Projects/myproject
 @ ./client.js 1:0-49

ERROR in ./app.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js' in /Projects/myproject
 @ ./app.js 1:0-49
```

Comment: I'm getting this as well.  Removing semver puncuation on webpack (and webpack-dev-server) works for me:  Looks like a `1.12.3` issue.

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1596

Comment: yeah that seems to be the issue, reverting back to 1.12.2 fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/hapijs/qs/issues/128

I think it is a know issue. You can always go back to a previous version.

Comment: How did you go back to previous version..?? Should I just install previewous version again..??? like npm install webpack@1.12.2..?? Thanks.. :)